# Valgrind reports silly arg to malloc, how do I find out where?

Tags: c, memory, valgrind

I get a warning when running my program under valgrind:

```
==24214== Warning: silly arg (-1) to malloc()
```

How can I determine what call to `malloc()` is faulty? Is there a way I can do this without recompiling?

> The program is compiled with `-g` (debug) and without `-s` (strip).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up inserting `printf`'s and finding if it came before or after the valgrind `printf`. Less fancy than what you guys reccomended, but it worked faster than trying to implement the other solutions.

Comment: Well, for a small program the simplest solution is probably the best.

Answer (score 1):

After a modicum of experimentation on a relatively antique RedHat Linux with Valgrind version 3.2.1, it appears that it does not produce a more precise warning.  Further, even Valgrind 3.7.0 on Mac OS X 10.7.3 doesn't do a better job of identifying the erroneous call.

Test code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
int main(void)
{
    int   l = -1;
    char *x = malloc(l);
    return (uintptr_t)x & 1;
}
```

So, since `valgrind` does not help, you are probably reduced to using the debugger on the program, breaking on calls to `malloc()` — perhaps conditionally breaking when the argument is equal to `(size_t)-1`.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, it appears that valgrind refuses to print a stack trace for this situation, even with `--verbose`. Please write to the mailing list; there should be an option for this otherwise the diagnostic isn't that helpful.

Note that the argument of `malloc` is an unsigned type, `size_t`, which does not have -1 in its range. What this situation means is actually that the largest possible value of `size_t` was passed to `malloc`.

Strictly speaking, that is not an erroneous API call, but it does probably indicate that something is wrong. (Your program does not need multi-gigabyte arrays, right?)

Answer (score 0):

you can do a break point on malloc and make it conditional, for example that the arg is <0

Comment: +1, tho it won't hurt if you could also provide a simple gdb command for conditional breaks as an example.

Comment: You cannot break on malloc because there are no debugging symbols for it.

Comment: you can however use find-and-replace to replace malloc() with a two-statement line, i.e. #define wrapped_malloc(x) malloc(x); (void)0; and set a breakpoint there: it *can* break on (void)0. One only needs to branch the codebase and find the error, the change doesn't have to be permanent

Comment: the problem with find-and-replace is that i have the word `malloc` at the end of a lot of function names.

Comment: oh man that's harsh. well, use a regular expression that looks for '= malloc(*)' or '= (*)malloc(*)'. I'm not a big regex guy so I wouldn't be able to suggest exactly which one to use.

Answer (score 0):

You might find where that text "silly arg" gets called inside valgrind.  Bring up your debugger and break on that spot.  Run your program and when it brings you back to the debugger prompt go up until you're at the line that called the malloc.